# Changing the response of an API value to something else

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm pulling data from an API and putting it into a discord embed with fields and values, I want to make it so if a specific value comes back as "None" it changes it to "Not Found" but after fiddling with it for like an hour I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
  if item:
    itemdesc = item['description']

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Item API Search Result", color=0xc600bc)

    embed.add_field(name='Description', value=itemdesc, inline=False)
```

Comment: "with code and crap" - I'm in tears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's the description field you're referring to, try:

```
itemdesc = item['description'] if item['description'] else 'Not Found'
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for description but I also want to do it for the item type which is itemobtaintype = item['obtained']['type'] and that didn't change anything when I added if item['obtained']['type'] else 'Not Found'

Comment: In the api it shows as this:
`description: null
obtained: {obtained: "Free", type: "none"}
obtained: "Free"
type: "none"`

Comment: null and "none" are two very different things. `null`, or `None` in python, is considered falsey - meaning it will equate to false in a condition. That's why the above code works. "none" is a string, strings are truthy, doesn't matter what they say, they will always equate to true in a conditional statement. So, you need to be more specific for that one: `item_type = ['obtained']['type'] if ['obtained']['type'] != 'none' else 'Not Found'`

Comment: Note that your API response calls it `null`, but that gets converted to `None` in Python. Each language is slightly different, but they mean roughly the same thing.